# Xamarin: работа с xml из ресурсов

Tags: android, c#, .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Пишу проект на Xamarin.Forms (для Android). 
Пытаюсь загрузить XML-файл из ресурсов командой (из основного проекта)

```
XDocument xdSave = XDocument.Load("save.xml");
```

Но при выполнении выходит ошибка "Не найден файл". 
Файл "save.xml" добавлен в папку "Resources" проекта .Droid, отмечен как "AndroidResource"

Не понимаю, в чем проблема
Причем, например, картинки нормально загружаются, код

```
imgImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("drawable/icon.png");
```

работает нормально.
Вообще, как работать с файлами из ресурсов?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [документация](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/) по поводу ресурсов в Xamarin/Android.

Ресурсы доступны по id, который в свою очередь можно найти в классе `Resource` (и подсмотреть в файле `Resource.designer.cs`). Если ваш xml-файл лежит в каталоге `Resources/xml`, id должен быть доступен как `Resource.xml.save` или что-то наподобие.

Имея id, вы можете получить по нему XML при помощи [`Resources.GetXml(id)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetXml/p/System.Int32/). Это даст вам `XmlReader`, из которого [можно построить `XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
XDocument.Load(Resources.GetXml(Resource.xml.save))
```

---

Может быть, существует и более прямой путь, да (у меня нет под рукой на чём попробовать).

Comment: Этот код (Resources.GetXml) работает только в .Droid проекте.
А в основном он не работает. Тогда надо из основного как-то сслылаться на .Droid проект?

Comment: И все таки хотелось бы иметь доступ по имени. И, например, если нужно будет создать новый .xml файл из кода - такой способ ведь не подойдет?

Comment: @Theonic: Ну, вам нужно получить экземпляр Resources. Может быть `activity.GetResources` или `activity.Resources`, или `context.Resources`, или как-то ещё, зависит от того, что у вас есть.

Comment: Создать новый файл так не пойдёт — вы не можете изменять скомпилированную программу. Новый файл нужно класть в выделенный приложению storage. Ресурсы для этого не предназначены.

Comment: @Theonic: Возможно, id локальны в проекте, если так, вам нужно выделить публичную функцию, которая будет выдавать нужный `XDocument`, в одном проекте, и вызывать её из другого.

Comment: А как обращаться к выделенному приложению storage?